# $location.path() в safari

Tags: angularjs, safari

Имеется следующая проблема. Есть приложение, написанное на angular 1.5 +, сервер на java. И есть код для авторизации по токену при переходе с другого сайта.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', onRouteChangeStart);
```

внутри функции `onRouteChangeStart` есть условие:

```
if ($location.path() === '/login') {
   var token = $location.$$search;
   userService.loginByToken(token).then(function (response) {
   });
}
```

во всех браузерах это работает правильно, но в safari встречается баг, что при переходе иногда `$location.path()` возвращает пустую строку вместо `/login`.

Даже не знаю, как это пофиксить.

Comment: Попробуй в onRouteChangeStart добавить $window.location.reload(true);

Comment: или попробуй использовать в условии $window.location.href == '/login';